# How can I change the password of store and alias in a signing certificate?

Tags: android, keytool

I want to change the password of store and an alias in a signing certificate.Can anyone tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Keystore, you can use. It's interactive and will ask you for current and new password

`keytool -storepasswd -keystore <keystore-name>`

For Alias, try this

`keytool -keypasswd -keystore <keystore-name> -alias <alias-name>  -keypass <old-password>  -new <new-password>`

Answer (score 2):

Use keytool, the following command should work a charm :)

```
keytool -keypasswd  -alias <key_name> -keystore my.keystore
```

[Check out this link](http://vivekbhusal.com/changing%20android%20keystore%20password)

Comment: Thanks but this is half answer.

Comment: @AbhishekBirdawade Actually the link is a full answer